# Start xdebugging PHP script from iPad

Tags: php, xdebug, phpstorm

I know most bookmarklets use a cookie to trigger debugging to start. Can the same be done via  GET parameter?

I'm hoping to mod_rewrite this into the URL, so API requests coming from an iPad (or any device really) can trigger debugging.

(I'm using PhpStorm/XDebug btw).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that for xdebug.

http://xdebug.org/docs/remote -- scroll to "HTTP Debug Sessions" section (somewhere in the middle of the page).

Send `XDEBUG_SESSION_START=name` parameter (GET or POST) to start session with `IDEKey` as `name`

Send `XDEBUG_SESSION_STOP` (no parameters) to stop such session and destroy the debug cookie.

**P.S.**
But maybe it would be simpler to use browser extension to initiate such session when required? This depends on your actual requirements, of course.

Comment: I don't think I can use the browser extension, because I'm trying to debug API requests. Also, it looks like that forces xdebug to just send a cookie, which the clients I'm using don't honour unfortunately. Perhaps it's not possible at all.

Comment: What is not possible? GET parameter works -- at very least for the first page that is being requested (that's if cookies are not supported by client -- in this case you need to have such GET parameter on every page request).

Answer (score 0):

All cookies that xdebugger looks at can also be sent as request parameters http://kb.zend.com/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=434

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(iPad).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?start_debug=1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Does this only apply to Zend Debugger, not XDebug?